# Magento product pages load at the bottom and not the top

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, magento, magento-1.7

When product pages are loaded on this site http://www.gmsuppliesltd.co.uk/

they seem to load at the bottom and I can't seem to find the problem, can anybody help?

on any product page it loads at the bottom of the page, rather than the top, so you don't see the pictures ect when you first hit a product page

Comment: Can't see what it is Gavin but I'd suggest looking at your product pages to see what elements/files that they have that the other pages don't have and that may help you narrow down the cause of the strange behaviour.

Comment: no idea what you are on about here...more info please

Comment: if you load a product page, the focus for the page is at the bottom? @Andrew

Comment: @andrew if you load this page [link] http://www.gmsuppliesltd.co.uk/blizzard-bcc2-refrigerated-gastronorm-counter you will see the focus is on the bottom of the page and you have to scroll up. I'm pretty sure its a javascript issue, but i can't find where and its only on product pages.